# jsonschema: List of elements with exactly one default element

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema

I'm struggeling a bit with jsonschema validation. I have a list of elements that have some predefined fields. Exactly one of these elemets should have a `default` field defined. So something like this:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "item1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "item2",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "item3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Validation should fail if none of the items have a `default` field, or more than one. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `maxContains` keywords from JSON Schema draft 2019-09.

Firstly, in order to use min/max contains, you need to define [`contains`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#section-9.3.1.4)

> An array instance is valid against "contains" if at least one of its
> elements is valid against the given schema.

Next, you need to set both [`maxContains][2] to` 1`.

> An array instance is valid against "maxContains" if the number of
> elements that are valid against the schema for "contains"
> [json-schema] is less than, or equal to, the value of this keyword.
>
> If "contains" is not present within the same schema object, then
> this    keyword has no effect.

You don't need to set `minContains` because it is implicitly `1` by virtue of using `contains`.

> A value of 0 is allowed, but is only useful for setting a range of
> occurrences from 0 to the value of "maxContains".  A value of 0 with
> no "maxContains" causes "contains" to always pass validation.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "properties": {
    "items": {
      "contains": {
        "required": ["default"]
      },
      "maxContains": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a live demo with your instance JSON to play with: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/p0RQ2hvY